# Hot to use empty item in description environment?

Tags: lists, description

I am using the `description` environment to give some extra reasons for the items. However, some items are obvious and don't need reasons. Leaving them empty puts a large blank line, because I have set the descriptions to go on the next line

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{enumitem} % configure labels of items in enumerations i.e. i), ii)
\setlist[description]{style=nextline,font=\normalfont\textbullet\space,labelindent=\parindent}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[Obvious item]
    \item[Not so obvious] So we need a small reason, which can span multiple lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines
    \item[Also obvious]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

If I'm doing this wrong, any advice is welcome ! :) .

**Edit:** The ugliest hack so far is to use `\item[Obvious item\vspace{-1.5em}]` which `seems right to my eye™️`.

To add: I'm using `description` with `nextline` because this kind of respects the logical formatting and I'm thinking of improving the style later (e.g. make the term bold). This would be (I think) more difficult if I used a replacement such as `itemize` with manual line breaks

Maybe I could patch `description` to detect empty item description ?

Answer (score 4):

Massage the body so you transform your `description` into `itemize` (and get alignment right).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{environ,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{ctdescription}
 {
  % remove possible \par generated by blank lines before \item
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \BODY { \par\item } { \item }
  % add a trailing delimiter
  \tl_put_right:Nn \BODY { \ct_item_end: }
  % replace \item by \ct_item_end: \ct_item:w
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \BODY { \item } { \ct_item_end: \ct_item:w }
  % remove the spurious leading \ct_item:w
  \tl_set:Nx \BODY { \tl_tail:N \BODY }
  % produce the environment
  \begin{itemize}\BODY\end{itemize}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ct_item:w [#1] #2 \ct_item_end:
 {
  \item #1 \tl_if_blank:nF { #2 } { \mbox{} \\ \tl_trim_spaces:n { #2 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{ctdescription}
\item[Obvious item]
\item[Not so obvious] No we need a small reason, which can 
  span multiple lines lines lines lines lines lines lines 
  lines lines lines lines lines
\item[Also obvious]
\end{ctdescription}

\end{document}
```

Note that a trailing blank line is not allowed, but they're allowed before `\item`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An even more ad-hoc proposal: why not forget about description altogether?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize} 
    \item Obvious item
    \item Not so obvious \\
          So we need a small reason, which can span multiple lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines
    \item Also obvious
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This should produce the displayed output.

Comment: I was thinking that I do description now, as it marks the logic nicely, and then I can easier change the formatting (make the item bold, use numbers, what not).  I'm curious to see if anyone proposes a `\vpace{-1.5em}` to be properly ad-hoc ^^

Comment: Sure, if it serves the structure of the rest of your document, then you'd rather keep `description`. Have you tried anything with `vspace`, yet? If so, add it to your question as an addendum and people might start from there.

Answer (score 2):

A very ad hoc proposal: forget about `nextline`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{enumitem} % configure labels of items in enumerations i.e. i), ii)
\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont\textbullet\space,labelindent=\parindent}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[Obvious item]
    \item[Not so obvious]~\\ So we need a small reason, which can span multiple lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines lines
    \item[Also obvious]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, marmot ! It would be a solution if I were to start now. But I already have description in many parts, with a bit more items than the MWE, all of which require description :). The obvious item is an isolated one among many

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă I see. In principle my proposal would just amount to regex search and replace...